# How can I query the percentage of a value to the total of all values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a table called credit_hours. The table has fields College and Sum_Credit_Hours and I want to calculate the percentage of each "Sum_Credit_Hours" value as it relates to the sum of all credit hours. How can I achieve this?

Sample Data:

```
College      Credit_hours
------------ ------------
Liberal arts 2253.2
Social Work  442.2
Nursing      223.65
Nursing      2
```

Expected Result:

```
College      Credit_hours     Percentage
------------ ------------     ----------
Liberal Arts 2253.2            77
Social Work  442.2             16
Nursing      225.65            7
```

I currently have the following

```
SELECT College,
       sum(credit_hours),
       Percentage=( credit_hours / Sum(credit_hours)OVER() ) * 100
FROM Student_credit_hour_copy
```

However SQL server is stating that

> Column 'Student_credit_hour_copy.COURSE_COLLEGE_NEW' is invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

Which is strange, because it uses two `aggregate` functions in the `select`.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result. Also, what have you done so far?

Comment: How are you going to get total count to get average i.e. divide sum_credit_hours with?

Comment: Added sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Sum() Over()` window function to find the sum of all `credithours` and divide the each `credithours` with the sum to find the `percentage`

```
SELECT college,
       credit_hours,
       Percentage=( credit_hours / Sum(Credit_hours)OVER() ) * 100
FROM  (SELECT college,
              Sum(credit_hours) credit_hours
       FROM   Yourtable
       GROUP  BY college) a
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d169c2/1)

Comment: Something like this would be the ideal solution, but SQL Server keeps demanding that I place credit_hours in a GROUP BY clause, which doesn't make sense because it is acted upon by two aggregate functions already.

Comment: Yes, and it's stating that it expects credit_hours in the group by clause

Comment: @KinsDotNet - You must be kidding.. Added demo check that

Comment: Yours works, but I also need to calculate the sum of credit_hours when selecting it. I edited my question. Check again.

Answer (score 0):

For the exact code, we'll need to see what your data structure looks like.
But if you have a query that gives you the sum, it'll be the same query with avg in it's place. You may have to round it though.

So, something like,

```
Select sum(column1) Total_Column1, avg(column1) Average_Column1
from table_name
Group by PK_Column
```